# How to include NA in ifelse?

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to create a column `ID` based on logical statements for values of other columns. For example, in the following dataframe

```
test <- structure(list(time = c(10L, 20L, NA, 30L), type = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, NA), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), ID = c(NA, 
"1", NA, NA)), .Names = c("time", "type", "ID"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

which looks like

```
    time    type
1   10      A
2   20      B
3   NA      C
4   30      NA
```

I want to make a new column `ID` containing a value of 1 for all `time` that are not `NA` and all `type` that are not `A`. I am using the following code for this:

```
test$ID <- ifelse(is.na(test$time) | test$type == "A", NA, "1")
```

This gives the result as

```
    time    type    ID
1   10      A       NA
2   20      B       1
3   NA      C       NA
4   30      NA      NA
```

However, this code ignores the `NA` in column `type`, resulting in a value of `NA` in column `ID`. I need this to be a value of 1, so my needed solution should give:

```
    time    type    ID
1   10      A       NA
2   20      B       1
3   NA      C       NA
4   30      NA      1
```

Can anyone tell me how I might do this? I could get this to work with my existing code if I could somehow change the result of `is.na(test$type)` to return `FALSE` instead of `TRUE`, but I'm not sure how to do that. Or, maybe the structure of my existing code needs to be entirely changed?  I appreciate any help!

Comment: You have two conditions (time<>NA, and type<>A). Sounds like you need a nested ifelse().

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can't really compare `NA` with another value, so using `==` would not work. Consider the following:

```
NA == NA
# [1] NA
```

You can just change your comparison from `==` to `%in%`:

```
ifelse(is.na(test$time) | test$type %in% "A", NA, "1")
# [1] NA  "1" NA  "1"
```

---

Regarding your other question,

> I could get this to work with my existing code if I could somehow change the result of `is.na(test$type)` to return `FALSE` instead of `TRUE`, but I'm not sure how to do that.

just use `!` to negate the results:

```
!is.na(test$time)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like you want the ifelse statement to interpret NA values as FALSE instead of NA in the comparison. I use the following functions to handle this situation so I don't have to continuously handle the NA situation:

```
falseifNA <- function(x){
  ifelse(is.na(x), FALSE, x)
}

ifelse2 <- function(x, a, b){
  ifelse(falseifNA(x), a, b)
}
```

You could also combine these functions into one to be more efficient. So to return the result you want, you could use:

```
test$ID <- ifelse2(is.na(test$time) | test$type == "A", NA, "1")
```

Answer (score 6):

@AnandaMahto has addressed why you're getting these results and provided the clearest way to get what you want. But another option would be to use `identical` instead of `==`.

```
test$ID <- ifelse(is.na(test$time) | sapply(as.character(test$type), identical, "A"), NA, "1")
```

Or use `isTRUE`:

```
test$ID <- ifelse(is.na(test$time) | Vectorize(isTRUE)(test$type == "A"), NA, "1")
```

Answer (score 2):

You might also try an elseif.

```
x <- 1
if (x ==1){
    print('same')
} else if (x > 1){
    print('bigger')
} else {
    print('smaller')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I hear this works:

```
Data$X1<-as.character(Data$X1)
Data$GEOID<-as.character(Data$BLKIDFP00)
Data<-within(Data,X1<-ifelse(is.na(Data$X1),GEOID,Data$X2))
```

But I admit I have only intermittent luck with it.