# Trouble with >= and ifelse in R

Tags: r, if-statement

This is related to a previous question at [R: How to include NA in ifelse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22076353/r-how-to-include-na-in-ifelse).  I am trying to create a column `ID` based on logical tests using values from a number of different columns. For the following example dataframe:

```
test2 <- structure(list(time1 = c(10L, 20L, NA, NA), time2 = c(5L, NA, 
10L, NA), size = 1:4, type = structure(1:4, .Label = c("A", "B", 
"C", "D"), class = "factor"), ID = c("6", "6", NA, NA)), .Names = c("time1", 
"time2", "size", "type", "ID"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

which looks like

```
    time1   time2   size    type    
1   10      5       1       A       
2   20      NA      2       B      
3   NA      10      3       C      
4   NA      NA      4       D
```

I want to create a column `ID` containing a value of 6 when the following conditions are met: 1) either `time1` or `time2` is not NA, 2) `size` is greater or equal to 2, and 3) `type` is not equal to C or D. I have been trying the following code:

```
test2$ID <- ifelse(is.na(test2$time1) & is.na(test2$time2) & test2$size >= 2 | test2$type %in% "C" | test2$type %in% "D", NA, "6")
```

For some reason, the "greater than or equal to 2" statement is not working properly. This code gives me the solution

```
time1   time2   size    type    ID
1   10      5       1       A       6
2   20      NA      2       B       6
3   NA      10      3       C       NA
4   NA      NA      4       D       NA
```

However, the solution I need should be

```
time1   time2   size    type    ID
1   10      5       1       A       NA
2   20      NA      2       B       6
3   NA      10      3       C       NA
4   NA      NA      4       D       NA
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

**Also:** I am having a hard time understanding how logical operators work in R. It seems these are evaluated sequentially, so that X & Y | Z is not equivalent to Z | X & Y. Is this correct? Could I make a statement link (X & Y) | Z and this would be equivalent to Z | (X & Y)? Sorry for the silly question!

Comment: You answered it yourself basically.  Use parentheses the way you describe.

Comment: In fact I use parentheses fairly liberally in logical statements since I think it helps the readability.

Comment: Thanks - really appreciate the help. again, sorry for the silly question but this is new to me and it's been a long day.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
test2$ID <- with(test2, ifelse( (!is.na(time1) | !is.na(time2)) &
                   size >= 2 &
                   !type %in% c("C", "D"), 6, NA))
```

Yes like you said you can use parentheses to force `&` to evaluate before `|`.

Comment: Thanks - that worked perfectly. This will really help out with the rest of my code!

Comment: Yep, this is the way to go. The readability could be improved a lot by using `with(test2, ifelse(...) )` so you can just use `time1` instead of putting `test2$time1` etc every time. Also, formatting each conditional statement to a new line helps in picking up these errors.